# Garch(1,1) in R

Tags: garch

I'm evaluating the impact of two variables on stock returns. For this I am using a Garch(1,1)-model in RStudio. This is the result I am getting. Why is the garch model not a valid choice? The external regressors are in the variace model, because they are not incorporated in the mean equation.

```
> myspec<-ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGarch", garchOrder=c(1,1),external.regressors=mydata),
+                    mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,0),include.mean=TRUE))
Error: 
ugarchspec-->error: the garch model does not appear to be a valid choice.
```

Comment: Apparently it is because the sgarch has to be written as sGARCH.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I do not see how it could be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rugarch/versions/1.3-8/topics/ugarchspec-methods):

> List containing the variance model specification: model Valid models (currently implemented) are “sGARCH”, “fGARCH”, “eGARCH”, “gjrGARCH”, “apARCH” and “iGARCH” and “csGARCH”.

Other values than the ones listed are never valid.